# EntityFrameworkCore and net48

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I have a class library that offers some reusable sugar for `EntityFrameworkCore`, and it currently targets `netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1`.

I have projects that reference this class library, most of which target `netcore`, but a few of which target `net48`.

Updating reference to `net50` and `EFCore 5.0`, I discovered that `EFCore 5.0` [no longer supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms) targeting `netstandard2.0` / `net48`.

If I wish to have my class library consumed by both `net48` and `net50`, I believe I must either:

- limit `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` packages to version prior to 5.0 (`version=[3.1.10,5.0)`), or
- create two libraries:

  - one of which targets `netstandard2.0` and references EFCore `3.1.10`
  - the other targets `netstandard2.1` and references EFCore `5.0`

Is there a way to have a **single** library build to `netstandard2.0` referencing EFCore `3.1.10`, and `netstandard2.1` referencing EFCore `5.0`.

I assume this is not practical, and the "right" answer is two distinct libraries.

Comment: You need two libraries, potentially sharing the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet packaging provides a solution for this situation.  (I needed a NuGet 201 course!)

In the event this helps others, in my `.csproj`, I added:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
[...]
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.13" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

which, when packed with `dotnet pack myproject.csproj`, produces:

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="3.1.13" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        [...]
    </group>
    <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.1">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="5.0.4" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        [...]
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

When consumed by tests:

- targeting `.net48`, the `3.1.13` version is installed
- targeting `.net5.0`, the `5.0.4` version is installed

The downsides:

- Visual Studio's NuGet Manager cannot be used to update conditional versions; you will need to update these sections manually.
- Tests need to have a similar conditional section

**EDIT**: I found it convenient to create a "wrapper project" that manages this conditional reference: e.g. I have a `MyData` project / NuGET package that is a proxy for including `EntityFramework`. All other projects that need `EntityFramework` conditionally, simply reference the `MyData`. That keeps the `<Choose>` in just 1 project, and all other projects can go about getting latest as always.

Credit to [Mark Heath's article](https://markheath.net/post/csproj-conditional-references)